# NSOperationQueue returning __getNextReady bad access on resuming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

Here's how I start the code:

```
m_searchTimer = [[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(launchRequest:) userInfo:nil repeats:FALSE] retain];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:m_searchTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

then in my -(void)launchRequest method:

```
- (void)launchRequest:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    ASIHTTPRequest *req = [[[m_twitterQueue operations] lastObject] copy];

    [m_twitterQueue cancelAllOperations];
    [m_twitterQueue addOperation:req];
    [m_twitterQueue go];
}
```

once I reach the - (void)go; method, I get the bad access.

Any idea is welcomed

Comment: Don't forget to release the operation, since you created it by copying another operation.

Comment: Yes, you are right I forgot about it. Got stuck with that bad access and trying to figure it out. What's awkward is that if I move go before cancelAllOperations, it works, but it seems sketchy, since I want to cancel all the operations except the last one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue.

Using ASIHTTPRequest, there is a @property named

> shouldCancelAllRequestsOnFailure  //Default is YES

By leaving it on, you add a request while cancelling it which makes the queue crash.

Turning it False solved the issue.